# How do I join Amazon S3 multipart files back together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage

extremely basic question - how do i use the files created by an amazon S3 multipart upload?

i'm backing up wordpress websites in multipart `.tar.gz` archives to an S3 bucket (using the [BackWPUp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/) plugin). the uploads are working perfectly, but i'm afraid i don't understand what i'm actually intended *to do* with the multipart files once i need them. what steps should i take to create a working and complete website backup from the split files? in other words, how do i un-split the tarballs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about the [multipart upload functionality of S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), rather than some custom multipart feature of your client, then you **don't** use the uploaded parts.

Your client initiates a multi-part upload, then uploads the parts, then completes the multipart upload. That final step causes S3 to aggregate the parts back into a single file at which point you can access the file.

Comment: this is the correct answer. i stupidly confused myself previously by running the backup job twice and causing two backup files to appear in S3. multipart uploads in S3 actually automatically concatenate and i was wrong from the beginning. problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

To combine split tarballs, merge them into one file, e.g. `cat backup.tar.gz.* > backup.tar.gz`